# No se declara variable dentro de IF-ELSE en php

Tags: php, mysql

Aquí hago una consulta a la BD para saber si hay registros con el nombre guardado en $nombre_producto, para posteriormente ejecutar un INSERT INTO que solo se ejecutara si NO hay tales registros (segundo if), este es mi codigo.

```
    $igualdad = false,$comparador = $base->leerCondicionado("nombre_producto, id_producto", 'productos', 'pertenece_categoria' , $nombre_categoria);
    $a = 0;
    while ($a < sizeof($comparador)) {
        if ($nombre_producto == $comparador[$a][0]) {
            $igualdad = true;
        break;
        } else {
            continue;
        }
        $a++;
    }
    if($igualdad == false){
        if($base->insertar('productos', 'pertenece_categoria, nombre_producto, marca, medida, precio, estado, logo', $entrada_multiple)){
            $indicador = $contenedores->convertirId($nombre_categoria, false);
            include_once('collapse.php');
            echo json_encode([$indicador, $nuevo_collapse]);
        }
        else{
            echo 'error';
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'error';
    }
```

Al correr el código en Javascript (estoy usando ajax) lo único que hago es imprimir en consola la respuesta y dice que la variable $igualdad no esta definida (en la línea del segundo if), ¿Cómo es eso posible si estoy declarando la variable en el anterior condicional?

Edit: okay, este es el nuevo código, funciona. Lo que quería ya esta funcionando correctamente a partir de la segunda vez que se ejecuta, pero me sigue dando el error en el segundo condicional de Undefined variable $igualdad, lo que causa que la primera vez que se ejecute no envié bien los datos a mi ajax.

Comment: el objeto $conexion es una instancia del objeto mysqli

Comment: lo que quiero es que pueda ingresar una sola vez a la base de datos un registro con el mismo nombre, es decir, si no existe, que lo inserte, si ya existe, no solo inserte, y no puedo usar el UNIQUE de la tabla porque quiero insertar registros con el mismo nombre pero desde otro formulario, no desde este que es el que quiero que solo me permita un registro.

Comment: if($conexion->query($consulta)) no se esta ejecutando, puedes hacer la prueba definiendo la variable $igualdad de manera fija antes del if.

Comment: tambien probe, pero entonces el valor de $igualdad no cambia, es decir, como si el bloque entero del primer if-else no se ejecutara en lo absoluto, si declaro $igualdad = false, se quedara false así el resultado del condicional fuera true, y viceversa

Comment: Claro eso solo prueba que if($cone...) no se esta ejacutando, primero verifica que tu consulta esta bien compuesta, envía un echo $consulta después de crearla para verificar eso, si aún asi no logras encontrar el problema entonces debes chequear la conexion a la base de datos.

Comment: Comprobando con la consola de phpmyadmin pero con el metodo que me dices no.

Comment: Elimina la declaración $igualdad=false eso era solo para probar ; creo que el problema esta en la lógica de la consulta, has una consulta en phpmyadmin probando con los distintos parámetros que pones en tu consulta, los resultados deberían ser distintos si siempre obtienes lo mismo entonces el problema radica ahí en la lógica.

Comment: Solo imprime esto cuando trato de ejecutar el query, tanto con datos existentes en BD como inexistentes `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on bool in C:\xampp\htdocs\ProyectoPHP\0.0.4\practicas.php:11 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in`

Comment: Eso esta documentado, revisa este link, parece que la tabla no existe en la base de datos. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122374/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-fetch-row-on-boolean

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110171/discussion-between-carepollo-and-roberto-paillao).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque no guardas el nombre que pretendes insertar en una variable, luego creas una funcion como:

```
checkName($nombre){
query = "select id from tu_table where nombre = '?'";

$stm = $conexion->prepare($conexion, $nombre);
$stm->execute();

if($stm->rowCount()>0){

return false;
} 
return true;

}
```

Luego solo utilizas esta funcion y listo.